# Mouse doesn't work in installation but does in LiveCD

Tags: lubuntu, mouse

I did a clean install of Lubuntu 14.04 64-bit on my laptop. After the install the mouse stopped working. When I boot into the LiveCD the mouse works as it should. I am using a USB mouse as the touchpad mouse is shot. The mouse was working before. I had Lubuntu 32-bit installed and later realized that the computer was a 64-bit so I did a clean install of the 64-bit version. I've tried updating packages just in case but I don't see how that would affect the mouse operation. Especially since the mouse works in the LiveCD.

Comment: What is the model of your mouse?

Comment: Primax Electronics Ltd HP Optical Mouse